# Show $f(x) - f(c) = f'(c)(x-c) + g(x)(x-c)$

Tags: real-analysis

Show $f(x) - f(c) = f'(c)(x-c) + g(x)(x-c)$ where $\lim_{x \to c} g(x) = 0$

$f(x) = f'(c)(x-c) + g(x)(x-c) + f'(c)$

$\lim_{x \to c} f(x) = f(c)$  and

$\lim_{x \to c} f'(c)(x-c) + g(x)(x-c) + f'(c) = f'(c)(c-c) + g(c)(c-c) + f'(c)$

Am I on the right track to formulate this equality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $g(x)=\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}-f'(c)$ when $x\neq c$. Why is the limit as $x\to c$ equal to $0$?

Answer (score 2):

Define $$g(x)=\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}-f'(c).$$ If we take the limit as $x\to c$ we get that $$\lim_{x\to c} g(x)=\lim_{x\to c} \left(\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}-f'(c)\right)=f'(c)-f'(c)=0.$$ That is,

$$f(x)=f(c)+f'(c)(x-c)+g(x)(x-c),$$ where $\lim_{x\to c}g(x)=0.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Right. Thank you for noticing it.